# namespace to extend sharepoint built in webparts programatically in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to extend the features of image viewer webpart in my visual studio 2010 project. Which namespace i have to use to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the class by looking in the .dwp and .webpart files that are in your Site's Web Part Gallery.  That's how SharePoint knows which class and assembly to load. In particular, the image web part uses the class Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.imagewebpart.aspx#Y200

What is unfortunate for you is that class is sealed and thus you can't extend it.